# Is there any correspondance between UTM parameters and Apple ones (at, ct, mt, pt)?

Tags: app-store-connect, analytics, firebase-dynamic-links, utm-tracking, itunesconnect-analytics

I want to improve my Firebase Dynamic Links with analytics parameters as specified on https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually ("utm_source", "utm_medium"... but also "at", "ct, "mt", "pt" for the Itunes Connect Analytics from Apple).

I do understand how UTM parameters work and which one to fill in but I'm wondering if there is a simple mapping (correspondance) between the UTM ones and those from Apple?

Because when trying to find some information they never mention the Apple fields could be filled with the same value as for UTM parameters... any idea on this?

Here are the only documentation I found about those parameters:

- https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/en.lproj/static.html (look at the "Use your campaign and provider tokens" section)
- https://github.com/invertase/dart_firebase_apis/blob/main/generated/firebaseapis/lib/firebasedynamiclinks/v1.dart#L1461-L1473

Thank you,

Comment: hi Thomas, could you please help? maybe you know the answer, please help to answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75975164/how-to-connect-android-app-to-google-analytics-to-track-revenue-attribution-usin